# How to get alias ready to run rather than being printed?

Tags: linux, alias

So I have an alias in linux, when I run it its being printed but not executed. The problem with that is that everytime I have to copy the alias and then run it.

```
kartik>rg
simregress -l verif/sprsp_xcc_1d/reglist/gpsb_ral_reg.list -dut sprsp -notify
```

So now I have to copy this command in run it everytime. Instead I need to this command in the terminal ready to be run

```
kartik>rg
kartik>simregress -l verif/sprsp_xcc_1d/reglist/gpsb_ral_reg.list -dut sprsp -notify
```

This is how I am defining the alias

```
alias rg="simregress -l verif/sprsp_xcc_1d/reglist/gpsb_ral_reg.list -dut sprsp -notify"
```

Comment: If `kartik>` is just your prompt, please replace it with: `$ ` or something similar. Anyway, this is not how aliases usually work. See, e.g. [here](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-create-bash-aliases/). What is your shell / linux distribution? What is the content of your `.profile` and `.bashrc` (and similar)?

Comment: Please show the output of alias command, without parameters - ie: "kartik> alias <ENTER>"

Comment: when I run my alias command as $ rg, i simply get the output of alias printed.

Comment: I want something like this -> $ rg should give me $<whatever I have in my alias>

Comment: Your alias definition seems correct and so, when you run it, it should simply execute simregress with all specified options. Is simregress another script? Can you show its content?